# Name that pattern: using a collection of predicated handler objects as strategies

Tags: oop, design-patterns

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    bool Handles(IMessage message);
    void Handle(IMessage message);
}

public class FooMessageHandler : IMessageHandler …
public class BarMessageHandler : IMessageHandler …

public class MessageProcessor
{
    public MessageProcessor(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers) …

    public void ProcessMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        foreach(var handler in _handlers.Where(h => h.Handles(message)))
        {
            handler.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This has aspects of both the Strategy and Chain-of-Responsibility patterns, and perhaps the Specification Pattern as well.

Unlike a typical Strategy Pattern implementation, however, the strategy selection is performed by the handler objects themselves (like Chain-of-Responsibility and Specification), and one or more strategies may be applied (depending on the implementation).

Unlike the Chain-of-Responsibility Pattern, there is no chain -- the handlers are not composed hierarchically, are not aware of eachother, and again it may be that more than one handler is invoked.

This seems like a pretty common pattern for supporting extensibility (respecting Dependency Inversion and the Open/Closed Principle), but I can't put a name to it. I've seen the term "Handler Pattern," but that appears to be something else again.

Can anyone tell me what this pattern is called?

Answer (score 0):

It looks rather similar to the observer pattern in some ways.
The `IMessageHandler`s are the observers, and the `MessageProcessor` is the "observed object". Admittedly the handlers are passed to the `MessageProcessor` during construction rather than being added/removed via methods, and the handlers are called during construction rather than in response to some "change" in the observed object.